# Perl JSON - check if value exists before recording result

Tags: json, perl

I'm trying to pull out the doc_count value from the following json output if the key = tls, dns, or http.

JSON: https://pastebin.com/T5Cu3w79

So far I've attempted to print out the values for "key" but I could not get it to return a result. $hash is the JSON output stored as an array(s).

```
my @buckets = @{ $hash->{'buckets'} };
foreach my $proto (@buckets) {
    print $proto->{"key"} . "\n";
}
```

EDIT: See the JSON file here: https://pastebin.com/T5Cu3w79. The information I want are the "key" and "doc_count" values starting at line 818 and ends 859.

Comment: Please show a reasonable amount of code. What is `$hash`?

Comment: Your JSON data must start with `[` or `{`.

Comment: Your title and example refer to json, but your code shows a Perl data structure.  Which do you actually need help with?

Comment: The paste has been formatted with Dumper in perl to make it easier to view. I want to use perl to pull out the key and doc_count starting at line 818.

Comment: It would be better to show the JSON data that you're using. Please show the code that populates `$hash`.

Comment: The title of this question is misleading, since OP is really just asking how to access the data structure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given your pastebin data structure (which looks to actually be a decoded JSON structure), the "buckets" array you specify starting on line 818 can be accessed using its hash keys like this:

```
my $buckets = $hash->{'spi'}->{'prot-term'}->{'buckets'}; 
for my $proto (@$buckets) {
    # access proto->{'key'}, $proto->{'doc_count'}
}
```

If you wanted all the "buckets" arrays, **assuming the "buckets" arrays are always on the third level** of `$hash`:

```
for my $l1 (keys %$hash) {
    for my $l2 (keys %{$hash->{$l1}}) {
        my $buckets = $hash->{$l1}->{$l2}->{'buckets'};
        for my $proto (@$buckets) {
            # $proto->{'key'}, $proto->{'doc_count'}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. I didn't have the "spi" part myself.

Answer (score 0):

Given your last sentence, this seems to do what you need.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw( sum );
```

```
# Existing code to build the hash with buckets ...
```

```
my @buckets = @{ $hash->{buckets} };
my %count_keys = (
        tls => 1,
        dns => 1,
        http => 1,
    ); # lookup: which keys do I count
my %doc_count;

for my $proto ( @buckets ){
    my $key = $proto->{key};
    next unless $count_keys{ $key }; # not to be counted: skip this
    $doc_count{ $key }+= $proto->{doc_count}; # counting per type
}

print "$_: $doc_count{$_}\n" for sort keys(%doc_count); # output count per type
print "overall: " . sum(values(%doc_count)); # count of all doc counts
```

I am not certain, though, whether there are other questions / problems: have you decoded the JSON at all? It would be much more helpful if you had some more code to go on.

Comment: You've presented your solution as a complete program, but there's a lot missing. There's no `@buckets` declared, for instance

Comment: I've put in a comment indicating what I expect has already happened, and declared `@buckets`

Comment: Thanks. I've added a couple of breaks to underline that it's not a stand-alonefunctioning program